# View Pager swipe transition

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-transitions

I want to achieve following view pager transition on page swipe.Please Suggest me the approach to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

![required transition]: https://html1-f.scribdassets.com/53uvxqf53442v1re/images/3-8a20c30a8a.jpg

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this easy to use ViewPager that adds an awesome set of custom swiping animations.

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager.

Hope this helps.